# Analyze contents of a dump file

Tags: backup, freebsd, dump

Is it possible to extract some details from a file generated with the `dump(8)` command on a FreeBSD system? Preferably, I'd like to see the file sizes for each file inside, to see what exactly makes my incrementals so large.

I know there's the interactive mode with `restore`, but the most detail I can get out of it are inode numbers, which I find quite uninteresting.

Or maybe there's a way to mount a dump file as a loopback filesystem, that would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with BSD's version of dump, but on other systems, restore -Nt will list the files.

However dump/restore is a tool for backing up filesystems - not for backing up files. I would strongly recommend switching to using something else - tar, cpio are obvious choices, my own preference is afio.

Go talk to your business continuity provider - they spend a lot of time restoring backups.

C.

Comment: +1 switch to `tar` or `cpio`. Ultra-generic recommendation: tar is better for simple backups, cpio is better for complex backups (YMMV).

Comment: In FreeBSD, `-N` has a different purpose, 

And regarding a different backup scheme, I'm working on that as we speak :) Not necessarily because of the issue I have with dump files, but as you point out, I need more granularity.